# How to capture cell value change in datagridview in vb

Tags: vb.net

My code gives error when I click update button after I make changes to the value in the cell. I am trying to capture user id and date whenever there is a change in cell value in a data row. Please advise.

```
Private Sub DataGridView4_CellValuechanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView4.CellValueChanged

    Dim counter As Integer
    UName = Environment.UserName
    Dim now As DateTime

     If e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then
       For counter = 0 To (DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1)
            DataGridView4.Item(e.ColumnIndex, counter).Value = DataGridView4.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
            DataGridView4.Item("Modifieddate", e.RowIndex).Value = Date.Now
            DataGridView4.Item("ModifierID", e.RowIndex).Value = UName.ToString.ToUpper

        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Give me a hint, what is the error?

Comment: You do realize that you are changing the value of every row for the column that was changed. Is that your intent?

Comment: The last 2 lines inside the loop don't belong in the loop. You are just resetting to the same value over and over.

Comment: Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll. I am aiming for if any cell value changes in the row to capture the user id and date.

Comment: And what line causes the exception?

Comment: error at DataGridView4.Item(e.ColumnIndex, counter).Value = DataGridView4.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value

Comment: You really what to change the entire grid column to that one value? I didn't get the error but it locked things up for a bit. Every time a cell value is changed it will call the `CellValuechanged` event again. That is a real mess. What are you trying to do? I think they call this an X Y problem. You are causing your own problem by using the wrong approach.

Comment: please suggest right approach how to capture with simple code if a cell value changes in any cell of a data row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the `If e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then` is about. If it is a column that you don't want the user to edit then set the `Column.ReadOnly = True` and get rid of the If statement.

If you simply want to record the date and user who changed a cell in particular row.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView4_CellValuechanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView4.CellValueChanged
    If e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then
        DataGridView4.Item("Modifieddate", e.RowIndex).Value = Date.Now
        DataGridView4.Item("ModifierID", e.RowIndex).Value = Environment.UserName.ToUpper
    End If
End Sub
```